# can an applet be granted permissions from the applet tag

Tags: java, permissions, applet

I need some permissions to be granted to a self-signed applet. Is this possible without the user editing his .java.policy file? I was thinking something in the applet tag, since in JavaWebStart application permissions can be granted simply by adding a security tag to the jnlp file.

Also here [Java Applet Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620153/java-applet-permissions) it states
"applet methods called from JavaScript have no permissions, even if you explicitly grant them in a policy file"
is this by design... I kind of don't see the rational for it!?

Comment: For what exact reasons does the applet require extended permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Applets, by design, execute in a very controlled and isolated environment. The point is, obviously, to prevent malicious code from executing on the clients machine. If you could specify in the applet-tag the permission settings, that would make any security totally pointless since you (the developer) would still have full control over what your applet could do once it's running in the clients browser.

The rationale for the javascript limitation is the same. You should not be able to exploit security holes in a third-party applet through javascript, the applet should always remain in it's controlled "sand box".

Comment: The concept of the sandbox is clear, but in JWS the VM ask the users to grant the requested rights. I was thinking that something similar may have been added to applets and that I couldn't find its documentation (one can hope). Now I know not to look any further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an applet via JNLP. I think the jar needs to be signed. Info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/TOC.html